# How to use HyperlinkButton to show ContentDialog page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How to use `HyperlinkButton` to show `ContentDialog` page in Windows Phone 8.1.

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="Login/ForgotPassword.xaml">
  <TextBlock>
     <Underline>
         <Run>Forgot Password?</Run>
     </Underline>
   </TextBlock>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

`ForgotPassword.xaml` is a `ContentDialog` Page which is present in `View` folder.
By using this XAML code I am getting following windows screen on click event:

[image]

Which is not expected. Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HyperlinkButton.NavigateUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton.navigateuri.aspx) is used by WebView:

> The action of opening the NavigateUri in a default browser is a system action that takes place without requiring any event handling. If your intent is that the HyperlinkButton should load a specified URI within a WebView control that's also part of your app, then don't specify a value for NavigateUri. Handle the Click event instead, and call WebView.Navigate, specifying the URI to load.

If you want to navigate to a page in your app or show dialog, use [Click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx):

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // navigation to Page:
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ForgotPassword));
    // if you need to show a dialog (it must be defined somewhere in your page clas), then make the whole event async
    ForgotPassword dialog = new ForgotPassword();    
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
 }
```

In XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton Click="HyperlinkButton_Click">
```

Comment: `ForgotPassword` is `ContentDialog`, how to show it as Dialog box?

Comment: Got it, great answer thanks. You can add following lines in your answer to make complete: `ForgotPassword dialog = new ForgotPassword();

            await dialog.ShowAsync();`

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Note also that you can add your dilog to Page in XAML: `<local:ForgotPassword x:Name="dialog"/>`, then there is no need to define it in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {


ContentDialog testDialog = new ContentDialog()
{
    Title = "Testing",
    Content = "We are still testing this contentDialog",
    PrimaryButtonText = "Ok"
};

await testDialog.ShowAsync();


}
```